# Facebook login using Godot 3.1 in iOS

Tags: ios, godot, facebook

In my game I have to integrate Facebook login. I searched about custom modules and all.

I found [one](https://github.com/aldoram5/godot-facebook) but it not working in ios and its for older version.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Asking for tutorials and such is off-topic here, so I edited the question as such :)

Answer (score 0):

I [started this](https://github.com/DrMoriarty/godot-facebook) one, didn't try it yet though. Someone told me about it.

Comment: Thanks anyway. But I figure it out. Even i create tutorial for this

Comment: @PratikPrajapati where's the tutorial? I'd like to see it. Also if you got it to work, please consider answering your question and accepting your answer so that you help others.

Comment: Here is the video [Link](https://youtu.be/eOmpZzYMKOE)

Comment: Tried both for iOS with no luck. The one from Pratik is quite outdated. The one from DrMoriarty is a bit more maintained but still doesn't work. Not sure what I am missing..

Comment: @bashan i'll update my repo soon, and can you share what error you are facing?
or create issue in my repo. thanks

Comment: I opened on this repo few issues: https://github.com/DrMoriarty/godot-facebook/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/kurtsev0103/godot-facebook-auth)

If you're integrating this for iOS, you'll also need to implement login via Apple.

You can use the [Apple Plugin](https://github.com/kurtsev0103/godot-apple-auth) for this.

- Both plugins have detailed instructions for installation and use.
- Both plugins work on the same methods and signals for convenience.
- Both plugins support `Godot >= 3.3.3`